# Is it a bad idea to put the logo in the top-right corner and the navigation in the top-left?

Tags: design-patterns, layout, navigation, conventions, position

Firstly I would like to say that I don't think there is a concrete rule about where the logo on a website should be – but intuitively I think it should be in the top left at least for continuities sake.

Is it bad UX to have the navigation placed before a company logo and why?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This article might also help: [Jakob Nielsen: Horizontal Attention Leans Left](http://www.useit.com/alertbox/horizontal-attention.html)

**Extract**: People spent more than twice as much time looking at the left side of the page as they did the right:

- Left half of screen: 69% of viewing time
- Right half of screen: 30% of viewing time

Simply put: Stick to the conventional layout, because it works perfectly with how people look at Web pages:

- Keep navigation all the way to the left. This is where people look to find a list of current options.
- Keep the main content a bit further in from the left.
- The most important stuff should be showcased between one-third and halfway across the page. This is where users focus their attention the most.
- Keep secondary content to the right. It won't be seen as much here, but that's okay — not everything can get top billing, and you need a place to put less-important material.

Comment: One could argue that people look at the left part of the screen most of the time because that's where the menus are usually placed. I wonder if there are any studies or A/B tests that show that UX actually suffers from such unconventional layouts. As one designer put it, 'People tend to look at the things you point to".

Comment: @exizt: Good point, would indeed be interesting to see.

Comment: @exizt It's a valid point, but it doesn't change the reality that people *do* look at the left side of the screen first. So unless your goal is to change that behaviour, it's probably best to take advantage of it :)

Comment: I would say it depends. Properly done, you can align a logo right and place a call to action on the left. According to that same source, the eye moves in an F shape on the page.

Answer (score 4):

You have to decide what is more important for a company and then what is more representative for that company's website: the logo or the navigation.

The positioning of the logo in the top left corner is not a rule set in stone, it's a result of the research that tells us that the eye movement on a website usually starts from the left side. You need to read more on [**eye movement patters**](http://www.onextrapixel.com/2010/11/05/eye-movement-patterns-in-web-design/), especially about the **F-pattern** which is relevant in this case. The bottom line is that if you want the logo to be viewed first, then it would be a good idea to place it on the left side.

But, if you acknowledge this and still want to do something else, to be a little different, you could try to change things. I am sure the visitors will still see the logo.

Answer (score 2):

> Everything you read in the internet is NOT true! including all answers here.

I used windows for 16 years and now it's been only 2 years with macintosh.

I feel no strong reason for the close button to be in right. Actually there is NO scientific reason to justify. You know it is just convention. Remeber that, when a giant company put its logo in right, everybody will take that risk. It is just bullshit to keep saying logo in left.

In terms of Attention, One of key feature of logo is to stand out. If it doesnot stand out against the naviagion(in the left) and other stuff around it. Please don't call it LOGO

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say it's a concrete rule, but it's based on one's cultural preferences.

Western cultures read from left to right and in a way you can say that the logo is the first word in the sentence.

In right to left writing systems it will be more familiar for the end user to have the logo at the right and then continue with the menu.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it.
Putting the logo on the top right corner will leave more space on the top left corner for navigation and other useful controls.

Answer (score 0):

You do have to pay attention to mental models, what the user is expecting. Now a days, logo on the left and navigation on the right is a convention and a very intuitive layout. If you change it do make sure that your new layout is as intuitive as the other or even more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Liviu A, if you read and write from left to right, you (the user) will definitely focus on the content starting from left to right.

Knowing this, it's all about priority.

Have you ever wondered why when you watch TV the television logo is on the right (not on the left)? Because they consider it secondary. The main focus is on the broadcasted program and the logo is not actionable (you can't click on it) it's just informative.

On the web it's another story. The logo is actionable (part of the navigation), usually when you click it you go to the homepage.

So it's about prioritization/information architecture.